# Reminder Service in C#.Net 4.0 using UTC Time

Tags: c#-4.0, timezone, reminders

I have a Windows Service that runs on my

> **Texas origin Server Central Time.**

This will check for all active reminders and compares the reminder time that user wants and send out reminder if it matches with user required time.

**Scenarios**

1. User is from EST
2. User set up a reminder for **1:25 PM ** using UI via my website
3. On submit, my C# business logic converts this time to UTC before storing in my database. That will become **'18:25:00'**
4. My Business logic will pull all Active reminders from DB
5. And checks for reminder time if **current UTC time** and **Reminder setup time** *diffrence is less then 5 mins*, then it will send notification to that customer.

**this is how my logic written**

```
 DateTime CurrentDate = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
 TimeSpan currentTime = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().TimeOfDay;

 if (Reminder.DailyReminders.Any(x => currentTime.Subtract(x.ReminderTime).TotalMinutes < 5 
&& currentTime.Subtract(x.ReminderTime).TotalMinutes > 0))
    {
        if (Reminder.ReminderMedhodID.Equals(1))
        _email.ComposeEmail(Reminder);
    }
```

**My Problem is**
**currentTime** is always 1 hour behind to user requested reminder time SO my reminders are going out 1 hour late.

Note : currentTime is from below

```
TimeSpan currentTime = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime().TimeOfDay;
```

I am not sure if this is the best way to handle this requirement. considering this is one of the way, can any on help how to fix this issue?

**Thanks to peter's answer**

Can any one help me how to take user input time with Daylight consideration

This what i have so far

```
public TimeSpan ConvertToUTCTime(string dateStr)
        {
            DateTime localDateTime = DateTime.Parse(dateStr); // Local .NET timeZone.
            DateTime utcDateTime = localDateTime.ToUniversalTime();

            string clTimeZoneKey = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.StandardName;
            TimeZoneInfo clTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(clTimeZoneKey);
            DateTime clDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcDateTime, clTimeZone);
            if (clTimeZone.IsDaylightSavingTime(localDateTime))
            {
                // Get DayLight local time in UTC
                // Yet to be implemented
            }
            return clDateTime.TimeOfDay;
        }
```

I got this worked using this
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.daylighttime.aspx

Comment: Your CurrentDate object will need the Client's current date/time in order to do the calculation because you are storing the client's UTC.  In the above code, you are getting the CurrentDate via the DateTime.Now, which grabs from the Server.  This is why you are always one hour off.

Comment: @Steve  He's converting to UTC in both cases so it shouldn't matter where he gets the time.

Comment: 1:25 pm EDT is 17:25 UTC, not 18:25.  Somebody has to fix their daylight savings time setting.

Comment: @PeterGluck - Thanks, my bad on that one.

Comment: @HansPassant How can i check if Daylight for user and convert that to UTC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ummm...we are currently using Daylight Saving Time in most of the U.S. (though there are some portions of Indiana that did/do use EST?)  Since EDT is one hour ahead of EST, your logic is correct.  It is the input (EST) that is incorrect.

Comment: According to the documentation:

Comment: @Peter How can I correct my input with daylight and convert to UTC?